# WordPress Editor Missing Padding and Background Color?

Tags: themes, block-editor, editor, visual-editor, post-editor

For some reason, my editor has no left and right padding and I have no idea of how to get it back. It seems it has also lost its white background.

I'm using  `Twenty Twenty-Three` and I'm not sure at what time I lost it. (I've tried uninstalling all plugins and all custom CSS code)

[image]

The style that seems to be affecting it is:

```css
body .is-layout-constrained > :where(:not(.alignleft):not(.alignright):not(.alignfull)){
   max-width: var(--wp--style--global--content-size)
```

Or this

```css
.editor-styles-wrapper .has-global-padding {
    padding-right: var(--wp--style--root--padding-right);
    padding-left: var(--wp--style--root--padding-left);
}
```

The style seems to be defined with its default value at `themes.json`

```json
"layout": {
    "contentSize": "650px",
    "wideSize": "1200px"
},
```

I'm expecting to get some left and right padding like in here, where I'm using the exact same theme but somehow it works fine:

[image]

Regarding the background color, I can see the one without padding and without white background uses this style:

```css
.editor-styles-wrapper {
    background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--tertiary);
}
```

While the original theme uses:

```css
.editor-styles-wrapper {
    background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--base);
}
```

Where can I change this?

Can this all (padding + bg color) be related with the custom edit of the theme or the theme templates?

I'm a bit confused!

[image]

Comment: Are you using different plugins? I can see an overlay of some kind in the first screenshot.

Comment: Plugins are not related. Installing the theme again or applying others will fix the issue. Also uninstalling them won't solve it. I suspect it's related with the edits I made under `Apparence > Editor`

Comment: What changes did you make in _Appearance > Editor_?

Comment: @JacobPeattie quite a few! Like changing the background color to `tertiary` and many others. Difficult to say. But I wouldn't expect them to modify the "editor" view too! Just the `post`

Comment: Well the editor view is supposed to match what appears on the front end, so many changes will affect the editor view. Which specific changes could cause this specific issue is hard to say if you made many. Did you change the size/width of the Post Content block in the single post template at all?